# Best way to refresh a Treeview c# task timer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, task

I have a process (Task) that works with a Tree (C#). That tree is loaded from a postgre database. That process is listening to events. When an event occurs, the Tree is updated.

With another process (Task), I use the same Tree, to reflect the changes in a Treeview using a Timer.

It's very slow. So there is something that I'm doing wrong...

I need help to know what is the best approach to do this, information about books, examples of Thread, BackgroundWorker, Timer, Task, Real Time Systems, and so on.

Thanks!

Regards.

Comment: Have you got any problem with cross thread ?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16024/Cross-Thread

Comment: The first process calls another tasks ("secondary tasks") that are listening to events.In the first process, I am trying to know when the value of a variable is changed in "secondary tasks". Do I need to pass the objects shared between first process and "secondary tasks" by reference? Thanks!

Comment: would you release your code then i check your first and second process as well if you got some runtime errors please mention the code line\

Comment: In the first answer, is the example code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example similar to the code I am developing...There are 3 Classes: A, B and C. A is the "master" class. It has a list of B objects and a List of B Threads. Each B Object has a list of C Classes and C Threads.

C class is ready when an operation is done (in the example, put the variable "cIsReady" to true. When all the cObjects in the list, of object B, are ready, then "bIsReady" is set to true. When all the bObjects in the List, of object A, are ready, then "aIsReady" is set to true.

```
public class A
{
    private List<B> bList;

    private List<Thread> threadBList;

    private bool aIsReady;




    /// <summary>
    /// List of classes managed by A Class.
    /// </summary>
    public List<B> BList
    {
        get
        {
            return bList;
        }
        set
        {
            bList = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Threads. Each Thread manages a B Class.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Thread> ThreadBList
    {
        get
        {
            return threadBList;
        }
        set
        {
            threadBList = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates when A is ready.
    /// </summary>
    public bool AIsReady
    {
        get
        {
            return aIsReady;
        }
        set
        {
            aIsReady = value;
        }
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public A()
    { 

    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the A Class.
    /// </summary>
    public void startA()
    {
        this.bList = new List<B>();

        this.threadBList = new List<Thread>();

        // for example
        int numberOfBClasses = 3;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBClasses; ++i)
        {
            B bObject = new B();
            this.bList.Add(bObject);

            Thread bThread = new Thread(bObject.startB);
            bThread.IsBackground = true;

            this.threadBList.Add(bThread);


        }   // for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBClasses; ++i)

        // Start all the B Threads.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBClasses; ++i)
        {
            this.threadBList[i].Start();
        }   // for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBClasses; ++i)


        while (!aIsReady)
        {
            foreach (B bObject in this.bList)
            {
                if (bObject.BIsReady)
                {
                    this.aIsReady = true;
                }   // if (bObject.BIsReady)
                else
                {
                    this.aIsReady = false;
                }   // else [ if (bObject.BIsReady) ]
            }   // foreach (B bObject in this.bList)
        }   // while (!aIsReady)

        this.aIsReady = true;



    }



}   // public class A







public class B
{
    private List<C> cList;

    private List<Thread> threadCList;

    private bool bIsReady;










    /// <summary>
    /// List of classes managed by B Class.
    /// </summary>
    public List<C> CList
    {
        get
        {
            return cList;
        }
        set
        {
            cList = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of Threads. Each Thread manages a C Class.
    /// </summary>
    public List<Thread> ThreadCList
    {
        get
        {
            return threadCList;
        }
        set
        {
            threadCList = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates when B is ready.
    /// </summary>
    public bool BIsReady
    {
        get
        {
            return bIsReady;
        }
        set
        {
            bIsReady = value;
        }
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public B()
    { 

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Start B
    /// </summary>
    public void startB()
    {
        this.cList = new List<C>();

        this.threadCList = new List<Thread>();

        // for example
        int numberOfCClasses = 5;


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCClasses; ++i)
        {
            C cObject = new C();
            this.cList.Add(cObject);

            Thread cThread = new Thread(cObject.startC);
            cThread.IsBackground = true;

            this.threadCList.Add(cThread);


        }   // for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCClasses; ++i)

        // Start all the C Threads.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCClasses; ++i)
        {
            this.threadCList[i].Start();
        }   // for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCClasses; ++i)

        while (!bIsReady)
        {
            foreach (C cObject in this.cList)
            {
                if (cObject.CIsReady)
                {
                    this.bIsReady = true;
                }   // if (cObject.CIsReady)
                else
                {
                    this.bIsReady = false;
                }   // else [ if (cObject.CIsReady) ]
            }   // foreach (C in this.cList)
        }   // while (!bIsReady)

        this.bIsReady = true;
    }


}   // public class B






public class C
{
    private bool cIsReady;




    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the object is ready.
    /// </summary>
    public bool CIsReady
    {
        get
        {
            return cIsReady;
        }
        set
        {
            cIsReady = value;
        }
    }






    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public C()
    { 

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts C.
    /// </summary>
    public void startC()
    {
        this.cIsReady = true;          
    }

}   // public class C
```

So, when I put the following code under, a form load event for example:

```
A aObject = new A();

        Thread aThread = new Thread(aObject.startA);

        while (!aObject.AIsReady)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("A is Ready");
```

The aObject never is ready...

Thanks!

Comment: is this a question or answer ?

Comment: That is an example of what I am trying to do. Is not an answer.